# Finding Duplicates based on condition in SQL

Tags: sql

Consider the following case,

```
No.         Name    Tag
 1          ABC     X1
 2          DEF     x1
 3          GHI     x1
 4          JKL     x2
 5          MNO     x3
 6          PQR     x4
 7          PQR     x4
 8          STU     x4
 9          VWX     X5
 10         YZI     x5
```

Now I need to find the duplicates having the same name and the tag.

Ideally the result should be

```
No.         Name    Tag
 6          PQR     x4
 7          PQR     x4
```

Comment: Please specify you database like MS Sql server, MySql, Oracle etc.

Answer (score 3):

This will work on most RDBMS since you have not specified one.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    TableName b
            WHERE   a.name = b.Name AND
                    a.Tag = b.Tag
            GROUP   BY Name, Tag
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        )
```

Comment: Assuming No. is the primary key (it appears to be), the GROUP/HAVING can be replaced by simply adding a.[No.] <> b.[No.] to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use a tricky pair `where` clause this way:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (name, tag) IN (
  SELECT name, tag FROM t
  GROUP BY name, tag
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93c2e/1).

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM (
    SELECT  Name, Tag
    FROM    YourTable
    GROUP   BY Name, Tag
    HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
)x inner join YourTable b on x.Name=b.Name and x.Tag=b.Tag
```

Comment: This won't work, it doesn't return the "No." column.

Comment: Yeah @richardtallent, you r correct, I have edited the answer.